# dojo grid filter by dates

Tags: dojox.grid

Here is my problem:

I have a grid that displays a list of records along with the date of the record. With that in mind I created a filter form that will allow the user to filter the data based on the dates. The problem here is how can I filter the dates. Here is what I have so far:

MyGrid is populated from my datastore:

```
recordsStore:  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
```

url: "xhreq?action=getRecords",
   clearOnClose: true,
   urlPreventCache: true
   });

Inside my tablelayout I am using the dateTextBox For the user to add a date to filter on:

{
 name : "Date",
 field : "Date",
 width : "10em",
 type : dojox.grid.cells.DateTextBox,
 formatter : formatDateObject,
 constraint : {
 datePattern : 'MM/dd/yyyy',
 formatLength : 'short',
 selector : 'date'},
 editable: true
},

this is how I started working on filtering on my dates:
filter data from grid:

doFilter: function() 
    {
filter_standby.show();

inDate = "*";

if(filter_inDateFrom.attr("value") != "" || 
filter_inDateThrough.attr("value") != ""){
   {
totalDays = inDateThru - inDateFrom; store totalDays
date = date + totalDays;  // filter based on total days
}

Now is there a way to return the dates within a range? if not what is the best way to handle the dates?

Thanks